# EWS: Streaming Notifications vs Push Notifcations

Tags: notifications, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Microsoft Exchange introduced Streaming notifications as an alternative to pull/push notifications with Exchange 2010. Basic introduction on streaming can be found on this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312849%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) and [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api.aspx)

However, I cant figure out the actual advantage of streaming over push notifications.
The only advantage mentioned in the blog is **"..and you don’t have to create a listener application as for the push notifications."** Apart from that, are there any other advantages and disadvantages?
How do other factors like managing the subscription, re-subscription logic, scalability, max num of subscriptions, etc compare over push? Also, Streaming  subscription has a maximum alive time of 30 mins and I would have to re-subscribe every 30 mins? Isnt that a disadvantage for a large number of subscriptions(my application has to manage 20K+ mailboxes)?

Any light on the comparison factors would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason for Streaming Notifications (SNs) is Exchange Online.  You can't have EOL opening up an HTTP connection to an application potentially behind a firewall.  Even within a corporate network there are firewall issues.  I've had several cases where my app could not get Push Notifications (PNs) because of the firewall on its own server.

On the surface SNs would also seem to be more efficient because each notification is not opening up its own TCP connection, but rather they flow in on a single pipe.  After doing some Wiresharking on this, I'm not really convinced this is so because it seems like under the covers they're doing Long Polling, so each notification coming in will cause a new HTTP call back up to Exchange.

The 30 minute max is no big deal, just reopen the connection in the handler and you're done--you don't have to actually re-subscribe.  In fact, I am of the opinion that I want to lower that even more to say 3 minutes.  You apparently cannot add new subscriptions or remove old ones except within the disconnect handler.  (Try it, and you get errors.)

And yes, you don't have to code an HTTP handler, which is nice I guess.

Comment: I figured out the reopen = resubscribe part but still thanks for confirming. I dont quite agree that Streaming is efficient just coz it does not open up a new TCP connection. Doesnt it still hold on to a connection for a long time, as compared to push where a connection is opened only on an event? If this is true, will monitoring 20K+ mailboxes continiously, require 20K+ open TCP connections? If firewall is the only concern for going with SNs, I would be inclined to use Push for my case.

Comment: Well the trick is to batch subscriptions up into groups of max 200 on each connection, so your 20K MBs would only need 100 connections.  (Of course supporting 20K MBs is way more than a single server is likely to handle.)  Grouping is via EWS URL, with some extra Grouping Information in E2013, which only works in EOL right now...  But I digress.  You're right that the connection stays open for a "long" time.